# Random Forest algorithm as an input in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I've built, trained, and saved a RF algorithm model using Python having the following features:

1. Number of deleted files (integer).
2. Path (string)
3. Severity (integer)

Taking into account sk-learn doesn't deal with strings, I have converted the data using CountVectorizer. How to take the user input path (string) and convert it to the same format as the saved model in order to make Severity predictions? Note that the predictions using strings `print(clf.predict([[5, '/some/path']]))` result in error:

```
ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.
```

Comment: No, both solutions produce another error "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'CountVectorizer'"

Comment: Then please open a new question with a full [mre], explaining that these solutions do not work (and link also here).

Answer (score 0):

If your model takes the transformed path (i.e., converted using `CountVectorizer`) in the training phase, then you also need to apply the transformation in the inference phase. So, it should be something like this.

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
# recall that you have fitted it before
#vectorizer.fit(X_train)

print(clf.predict([[5, vecorizer.transform('/some/path')]]))
```